# MacBook Pro does not recognize audio from usb c external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, audio, high-sierra, usb

I have a 15" MacBook Pro 2017 running High Sierra 10.13.5. I use 2 external monitors, one at home and one at work.

MacBook won't recognize output audio device from monitor when I plug it in. It doesn't show up in the sound menu bar either, all sound is coming out of internal speakers each time.

This started happening recently, past week or two. It only works if I restart MacBook, but I have to do it each time I connect it to the external display. The problem is not specific to one monitor either, as it happens with two different monitors.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Try powering cycling the monitor to see f the audio get's detected.

Comment: @Allan I tried that, it's not helping.

Comment: There's a DisplayLink issue with 10.13.4  - it could be related:  http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos

Comment: I have the same issue, started happening with last update, they can't seem to be able to reach a stable system in which all the basic features work. I have to restart the computer all the time to get the sound back.